# Android studio TTS: Not reading text passed into speak() function

Tags: java, android, android-studio, text-to-speech

I'm working on an app which uses MLKit's OCR function to read text from an image, display it to the user and then use Android's TTS but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
        private TextToSpeech textReader; // Instance of Android's built in TTS
        private String multipleBlockText; // Empty to store multiple blocks

        // Initialise TTS
        textReader = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                textReader.setLanguage(Locale.UK); // Sets language to US, English.
            }
        });

        // OCR code goes here
        
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    detectText(); // Calls function for OCR from LKit library
                    // Reads text
                    textReader.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                } catch(Exception error){ // Error handling: Prevents app crash on no text readable
                    detectedText.setText("Error!");
                }
            }
```

I've declared the TTS in my mannifest also:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

But when I run my app, it'll display image text to the user, but TTS won't read it aloud. The OCR function works fine and text in the image is stored in the "multipleBlockText" variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!:

Instead of attempting to call the `TTS.speak()` function after `detectText()`, it can be called inside the detectText function as such:

```
// in function detectText()
...
    for (Text.TextBlock block: text.getTextBlocks()) { // For loop for each paragraph
        String blockText = block.getText(); // Local scope store for text detected
        multipleBlockText = multipleBlockText + blockText + " "; // Concat blocks to one string
    }

    detectedText.setText(multipleBlockText); // Displays text to user
    textReader.speak(multipleBlockText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```